# What is the time interval for Facebook to bundle pictures in album uploaded with API?

Tags: facebook, api, upload, photo

If you upload a picture through the API to a Page, Facebook puts these pictures in an album. If an album for the app doesn't exist yet, it creates one.

Now, when we upload a picture and another one within a minute, Facebook bundles these pictures when creating a status update about it. However, we would like to have EVERY picture uploaded have a status update themselves so that the text written with the picture is also seen.

Sometimes it works, but most of the time Facebook keeps on bundling. I guess it has something to do with time interval but what is that time interval? How can he prevent this from happening??

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not work for you, but this is what worked for me.

1. Add photos making sure that they are under "Only Me" not "Friends"
2. As you are adding them one at a time, click on the little clock underneath.
3. Make sure to add the year, month, and date on every single photo.
4. Yes, it can be the same date.
5. Write a description on each photo you added.
6. Go back to your main page and make sure they are not bundled.
7. Now you can click on the "Only Me" button and make it visible to "Friends"

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: question is asking about using the API, not via browser.